# How to create a gif with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, gif

Good evening ,

could you tell me please if there available to create a gif image from video ( mp4 ) file with duration 20-30 min ?
Just need gif image no larger than 15mb and if possible take pictures from all duration of video ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: gif should be comprised of 10 different screenshots across the videos length. So for example if a video is 30 minutes long a screenshot should be taken every 3 minutes and all the 10 screenshots should be turned into a gif.

Comment: How long should the output be? Should each screenshot last 1 frame, or some specific duration?

Comment: @llogan , thanks for answering me . You have already helped me with watermark before.  Output ( gif ) should be not larger than 15mb . Goal is to show with gif image what input ( video.mp4 ) file about . I hope you understand me. Thanks

Comment: if possible more like a compilation video, where it may have some 5 second snippets clipped together

Comment: GIF has no bitrate control method so there is no simple way to guarantee that the GIF stays below a certain file size.